# Images Mapped to Planes Render White

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

Feeble minded noob here.
My issue is with trying to map images to a set of faces.
Each one appears white, despite the image appearing in texture and material viewport shading.

I understand I need an Image which is attached to a texture and then to a material?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0SOwCTySdtAZWdaaUN6emNvSWM/view?usp=sharingm
[File.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0SOwCTySdtAZWdaaUN6emNvSWM/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks guys.

Comment: Your scene has a material set up which overrides any other material - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFYlF.jpg. Delete that and all the objects will render as expected.

Answer (score 0):

while in Blender Render, when you unwrap your model, in UV Image Editor, toggle to edit mode, make sure you select all the faces by press A once or twice, and remeber to select there the image, so you can see the UVmap over your image. I've just done this and it worked.

Comment: That won't work as assigning image texture to faces will only change something for texture / material shading (which works for OP), but not for rendering (unless using *Face Textures* which is not recommended).